# jQuery - Get data from a div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jinja2

I'm trying to access the data-id of my div on click. The domain models are projects and todos for users. This is my current implementation (working):

```
  // script-tag bottom of user-page.html, before footer include (jinja2)
  const projects = '{{projects | count}}';
  for (let i = 1; i <= projects; i++) {
    const click_id = `#clickable-${i}`;

    $(click_id).on("click", () => {
        const data = $(click_id).data();
        redirectToProjectPage(data);
    });
  }
```

and html:

```
  {% for project in projects %}
    <div id="clickable-{{loop.index}}" data-id="{{project.id}}" style="display:inline-block;">
       ... stuff.
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Now I've tried to implement the refactoring by using jQuery.each and jQuery.on by browsing SO and referencing jQuery documentation, but following code produces *undefined* for me. Note: in the html I swapped the id for a class of "clickable".

```
  $('.clickable').each(() => {
      const $this = $(this);
      $this.on('click', () => {
          const id = $(this).data('id')
          console.log(id) // produces undefined
          redirectToProjectPage(id)
      });
  });
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into the [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue).

Use `$(this)` in the click handler. For this to work you have to use a regular function, not an arrow function.

```
  const projects = '{{projects | count}}';
  for (let i = 1; i <= projects; i++) {
    const click_id = `#clickable-${i}`;

    $(click_id).on("click", function() {
        const data = $(this).data();
        redirectToProjectPage(data);
    });
  }
```

You're having the same problem in your `.each()` loop. It can't pass the current element in `this` to an arrow function.

[Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly, and thanks for supplying a great link!

Answer (score 1):

$(this) wont work if you use arrow function
if you need to use $(this), you should use function() {} closure
else if you need to use arrow function, you have to pass an event parameter and can use the element by $(event.currentTarget)

```
$('element').click(function () { 
    const data = $(this).data('id'); 
});
```

else,

```
$('element').click((event) => { 
    const data = $(event.currentTarget).data('id');
});
```